# difference between できることなら and できるものなら

Tags: grammar

is there some difference? is it somehow connected with the difference of もの and こと?

Answer (score 2):

They are practically interchangeable when used as an adverbial phrase meaning “if possible” before a clause that expresses a desire that is difficult or impossible to realize with 〜たい.

> できることならやりたい。
> できるものならやりたい。
> I would like to do it if I could (but I can’t).

The latter is less ambiguous, and therefore probably preferred as a means to express impossibility, because できること may also be understood as referring to a specific thing (こと) one is capable of doing.

> できることならやりたい。
> I would like to do it if it’s something I can do (within my capabilities).

Only できるもの can be used in a rhetorical command.

> できるものならやってみろ。
> Go ahead and do it if you can.

The speaker is challenging the listener to do whatever is referred to, thinking they will not be able to do it whether for a lack of skills or courage.

In contrast, the following would be understood literally.

> できることならやってみろ。
> Do it if it’s something you can do (within your capabilities).

Answer (score 2):

できるものなら sounds more emphatic, and it's typically used referring to something (nearly) impossible. It's commonly used to mock someone's inability or absurd way of thinking. できることなら can be used in similar situations, but it can be simple "if that's possible" or "if I can", too.

- 声優になりたい？ できるものならやってみろよ。
  <sub>(the speaker thinks this is impossible)</sub>
- できるものなら大学に行きたいです。
  <sub>(sounds like the speaker thinks this is nearly impossible in reality)</sub>
- できることなら大学に行きたいです。
  <sub>(sounds simply like "if I can" or "if I'm allowed")</sub>

Answer (score -2):

こと: occurrence / verb

もの: noun

examples:

> できることならテニスかも。If we're talking about what I can do, playing tennis (verb) might count.
> できるものならケーキが入る。If we're talking about what I can make, cake (noun) would count.

So yes, there is a difference, one being used to refer to a noun, the other to refer to a verb. Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought OP was talking about the idiomatic expressions such as 「できることなら、/ できるものなら、代わってあげたい(but I can't)」「できることなら、/ できるものなら、子供のころに戻りたい(but I can't)」 where できることなら/できるものなら means 可能なら "If possible (but it's not possible)"

Comment: @Chocolate It can mean both. Verbally, the ones I mentioned are used more to answer questions such as "What are you able to do?